# How to transfer app between iOS 9 simulators

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9

When I create a program and run it in iOS 9 simulator everything works fine. The app gets created and saved in path like:

**/Users/MichalKolar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/567DCC64-3388-4A7B-A14C-677210F1A24A/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/6E72B743-051D-4232-A3F6-7FB94A1F317E**

It is visible in the simulator and it nicely works. I want to give it to a friend of mine to do some testing:

1. I deploy the same simulator on his Mac and his xCode, same iOS version
2. I copy the folder 6E72.... to the same folder structure on his Mac
3. I verify that both the *.APP and hidden* .PLIST files are successfully 
   copied
4. I launch the simulator in my friends Mac...

...and I do NOT see the application there.

Please advise - what is wrong? It behaves this way even for the simplest application (just a blank page, no specifics)... Tested in xCode 7.1 and 7.2 beta. iOS 8.4 apps are not problematic, just the iOS 9 are.

Thank you!

Comment: You should use TestFlight to do private beta testing.

Comment: Cannot use TestFlight on Simulator.

Comment: I know.  What you are attempting is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do what you are trying to do. Btw why not building app on his Mac if he has Xcode ?

You must use TestFlight or Ad-hoc distribution to make available app for testers. Or if your friend is near you, deploy app directly on his/your iPhone.

Comment: I want just to give him the APP and that is it. I do not want him to see my sourcecode. It worked for iOS 8.4 nicely...

Comment: Good, but I think doing this way is a pain :) . Don't forget that not always app behaves same on simulator and device.